Bluetooth on Android Kotlin: startDiscovery does not always find surrounding devices
So I'm working on an Android Kotlin app that Bluetooth scans every 20 minutes and logs any addresses it finds. The idea is to later use these logs to determine when the device was near a specific list of Govee sensors. For context, these sensors measure temperature and humidity and the data can be extracted via Bluetooth by the officla Govee Home App. So far I have followed the official Kotlin documentation and have an application that scans for 60 seconds and lists the nearby devices correctly. The problem is that while some sensors appear instantly, others only appear very rarely on the scans, even though they are right next to the phone. I would assume that this has something to do with the sensor and the frequency it broadcast itself, but the Govee Home App and other Bluetooth scanner apps in the play store like BLE Scanner pick them up consistently and in a matter of seconds.
I have a hunch that it has to do with the fact that the registered receiver is filtered by BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND and is ignoring any signals that might be coming from the sensor, but I'm not sure if that is what is happening.
Does anyone have an idea of why this might be?
Any guidance or help is greatly appreciated. Here is a simple version of the code I'm using, in case it's helpful.
package com.example.chbluetoothtracker.bluetooth.handler

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log

class SimpleBluetoothController(private val context : Context) {

    private val bluetoothManager by lazy {
        context.getSystemService(BluetoothManager::class.java)
    }

    private val bluetoothAdapter by lazy {
        bluetoothManager?.adapter
    }
    
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    
    
    private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            when(intent?.action) {
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND -> {
                    val device: BluetoothDevice? =
                        intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                    device?.let{
                        Log.i("TEST", device.address)
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private fun startDeviceDiscovery() {

        // Registers receiver
        context.registerReceiver(
            receiver,
            IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
        )

        // Starts discovery
        bluetoothAdapter?.startDiscovery()

        // Cancels discovery and unregisters
        // after 60 seconds
        handler.postDelayed({
            bluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
            Log.i("TEST", "Stopped scanning")
        }, 60000)
        
    }

}



One problem in your code is certainly the use of startDiscovery(), which refers to Bluetooth classic. As far as I understand your question, you want to scan for Bluetooth LE devices, so you should use BluetoothLeScanner#startScan()
